# PHP Tools for Visual Studio. How to debug AJAX requests?

Tags: php, ajax, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have small project on PHP and I want to debug it with PHP Tools for Visual Studio. It works fine, debugger works great. But I have part of my project that works as a service, it listen AJAX requests from html pages and send responses in JSON format. In this situation debugger doesn't work at all. I set breakpoints in my php service file and it never fires, but I get correct response in client-side. So, my question is **how to debug AJAX requests with PHP Tools?**

I make an example of my client and server code to illustrate my problem.

**server.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['response'])) {
    echo json_encode('ok'); 
}
else {
    echo json_encode('cancel'); 
}

?>
```

**client.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <title>AJAX test</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#request" ).bind( "click", function() {
            var data = { response: "response" };

            $.ajax({
                url: "server.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                timeout: 5000,
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#response").text(result);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    $("#response").html(error.responseText);
                }
            }); 
        });
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
   <p>
     <b>Request: </b> <span id="request"><a href="#">Send request</a></span>
   </p>
   <p>
     <b>Response: </b> <span id="response">Here will be your response...</span>
   </p>
</body>

</html>
```

So when I set the breakpoint in the server.php on the line with if-statement it doesn't fire, but client side successfully receive server response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution on the [DEVSENSE forum](http://support.devsense.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=1230&p=5819&hilit=ajax#p5819)
In this case xdebug just doesn't know when it should start debugging. Easist way is to add to php.ini next line:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
```

And all works!

Comment: Note that Xdebug v3 [no longer needs](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) (supports?) `remote_autostart`. The linked upgrade doc says "`The xdebug.remote_autostart setting has been removed. Instead, set xdebug.start_with_request to yes`"

Comment: The link to the documentation (Xdebug 2 and 3) - https://docs.devsense.com/en/vs/debugging/configuring-xdebug#update-php-configuration